# SQL query: time difference

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time, view

This is going to seem like a lame question for all experts in SQL server views but...

So I have a small set of data that my client needs for reporting purposes. I have to admit that although I did ask them their reporting requirements, it isn't till now that I see that my db could be better optimised.

One of the pieces of data they want is the time difference between two tasks that may have run:

```
select caseid, hy.createdate
from app_history hy
where hy.activityid in (303734, 303724)
```

This gives me two rows (after edit) per case-submission which then have to be measured; but a few wiggles: 
Activity 303734 will always run, activity 303724 might run.
Each 303734 and 303724 combo match up. Conceiveably a case can have 1 un-matched 303734 with a matched pair afterwards on the 2nd submission. Matching these might be down to intuition. Not good.
There maybe more than one submission per caseid and if that is the case then both activities will run every subsequent time.
There is no way to write the submission number to this table.

The app_history table holds userid, caseid and activityid as foreign keys. The PK is the identity column ID.

Is there a better way to write the query?

AFter help from KM:

```
select
    c.id, c.submissionno, hya.caseid, hya.createtime, hyb.caseid, hyb.createtime
    ,CASE
         WHEN hyb.caseid IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(mi,hya.createtime,hyb.createtime)
         ELSE NULL
     END AS Difference 
    from app_case c
        inner join app_history hya on c.id = hya.caseid 
        left outer join  app_history hyb on c.id = hyb.caseid  
    where hya.activityid in (303734) and hyb.activityid in (303724) order by c.id asc
```

This nearly works.

I now have this issue:

```
460509|2|460509|15:15:39.000|460509|15:16:13.000|1
460509|2|460509|15:15:39.000|460509|15:18:13.000|3
460509|2|460509|15:17:52.000|460509|15:16:13.000|-1
460509|2|460509|15:17:52.000|460509|15:18:13.000|1
```

So I am now getting 1 row comparing each of the two for each of the four rows... mmm I think it is the best I can hope for. :(

Comment: When you say "always run" and "might run", does that mean their `createdate` might not have been set/is `NULL`?

Comment: If the activity is not run then it will not be written to the app.history table.

Comment: what version of SQL Server, and what is the PK of app_history (is it an identity?)

Comment: SQL server 2005. PK is app_history.ID

Answer (score 1):

USE LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    a.caseid, a.createdate
        ,b.caseid, b.createdate
        ,CASE
             WHEN b.caseid IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(mi,a.createdate,b.createdate)
             ELSE NULL
         END AS Difference
    FROM app_history                a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN app_history b ON b.activityid=303724
    WHERE a.activityid=303734
```

**EDIT** after a little more schema info...

```
SELECT
    a.caseid, a.createdate
        ,b.caseid, b.createdate
        ,CASE
             WHEN b.caseid IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(mi,a.createdate,b.createdate)
             ELSE NULL
         END AS Difference
    FROM (SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM app_history WHERE activityid=303734)                 aa
        INNER JOIN app_history                                                               a ON aa.MaxID=a.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN a(SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM app_history WHERE activityid=303724) bb ON 1=1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN app_history                                                          b ON bb.MaxID=b.ID
```

Comment: Actually I think that this doesn't work... Not the way I expect anyway. It seems to be comparing every 'b' row to each 'a' row.

Comment: Hi, I only have 3649 rows in app.history in dev. I get 55605 rows returned with the above query.

Comment: @Sean, is activityid unique in app_history??? if not, then this will not work.  You'll have to get the last entered row for each activityid and use the primary key values in the LEFT JOIN and WHERE

Comment: what is the primary key for app_history?

Comment: oh.. Ok. Yes activityid will be there many, many times in the history table.

Comment: ID is the primary key. This table stores the time and date and caseid for each line of history dialogue. It tells us that "userid=1 did activityid=1 for caseid=1 on 1/1/2009 at 1pm."

Comment: @Sean, in your question you said _"This gives me two rows which then have to be measured"_ that is why I thought activityid was unique. I'm confused as to why it would return two rows for your query but thousands of rows for mine. Also, my edited solution will compare the most recent entries of each action, which I'm not sure is what you are looking for???

Comment: @KM. Sorry mea culpa. Two rows per case-submission. A case can be submitted many times.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
select datediff(
day,
(select isnull(hy.createdate,0) from app_history hy where hy.activityid =303734),
(select isnull(hy.createdate,0) from app_history hy where hy.activityid =303724)
)
```